# Flag does not move in the wind in Game Enigne

Tags: game-engine, physics, cloth-simulation

My Flag does not move in the Game Engine.
I know how to make the flag work when not in the BGE, but when I move it over to the Game Engine the flag stops working.
What could be wrong?

Comment: to my knowledge it is impossible to get wind inside of Blender Game engine without faking it. You can get cloth simulations by using the `Soft Body` physics type, but then you have to figure out a way to pin up the flag. My thought  would be to create a short, loopable animation that could be played.

Comment: Here is a video about how to pin, I am not certain about how to get the wind still. http://www.blendernation.com/2014/11/19/setting-up-softbody-and-pining-in-the-blender-game-engine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by BlendingJake:

> To my knowledge it is impossible to get wind inside of Blender Game engine without faking it. You can get cloth simulations by using the Soft Body physics type, but then you have to figure out a way to pin up the flag. My thought would be to create a short, loopable animation that could be played.

*Posted to remove from un-answered list*